# LineChart plot data not filling its UIView

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, ios-charts

So I'm using the library iOS-Charts for creating a calendar. The calendar shows plots of each day for each month. So for 1 year I have 12 `UIViews` plotted with data from each corresponding month. So for January there are 31 points in the line chart (since it's 31 days in January), in February I have 28 plots and so on. However, the `UIView` does not get completely filled with the `LineChart`.

So for February it looks like 3 points are missing, since the plot is not stretching the entire `UIView`. I've tried everything I can think of, setting `autoresizingMask` for the `UIView`, or the `lineChart` (which is a `LineChartView`), as well as setting the `UIView.contentMode` for both. Nothing helps.

I set the `xRange` of the `LineChartView` to be the amount of points I want, which depends on the number of days in the month. I then proceed to create the pageView (which are `UIView's` used to plot the `LineChart` on). Anyone know what I'm missing here? Below are my settings for each individual `LineCharts`.

```
// Create and set LineChart
        var lineChart = LineChartView()
        lineChart.descriptionText = ""
        lineChart.delegate = self
        lineChart.noDataTextDescription = "You need to provide data for the chart."
        lineChart.drawGridBackgroundEnabled = false
        lineChart.userInteractionEnabled = false
        lineChart.xAxis.drawAxisLineEnabled = false
        lineChart.xAxis.drawGridLinesEnabled = false
        lineChart.xAxis.drawLabelsEnabled = false
        lineChart.drawBordersEnabled = false
        lineChart.leftAxis.enabled = false
        lineChart.rightAxis.enabled = false
        lineChart.legend.enabled = false
        lineChart.contentMode = .ScaleAspectFill
        lineChart.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleWidth
```

Comment: could you provide some screenshots so I can better understanding your problem? You settings above seems nothing to do with your problem.

Comment: @Wingzero I added a screenshot :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your screenshot, I am guessing the xIndex count in your LineChartData is the same. Your last data point 5496 on Feb view is aligned perfectly with 2457 on March view, which indicates the share the same x values count on xAxis.

Based on your description, you should have 12 LineChartData objects, and each line chart data has its own xValues and dataSets, which means 12 xValues and 12 dataSets. You need to debug on xAxis renderer to see if I am correct.

If not resolved, then you need to provide your chart data code. I don't think it's a bug, it's some kinds of mistakes you made while creating chart data.

Comment: And right you are, I was sending in the wrong value for the range. I was debugging this earlier but was looking at the wrong value lol, I should really name them differently. But you were correct, I sent in the wrong range value, rather than sending in the size of the current month array, I was sending in the first array each time. Thanks!